# Performing multiple actions on a list recursivly

Tags: forms, f#

How can I perform actions on a list recursivly?

Specificly in my case, I have a list with a tuple structure as follows:

```
// ("name", (startX, startY), (endX, endY))

let list = 
[
    ("rectangle", (10, 10), (90, 90));
    ("ellipse", (30, 50), (40, 60));
    ("ellipse", (60, 50), (70, 60))
]
```

I want to perform one action for items that are "rectangle"s and another action for the items that are "ellipse"s.

Comment: This is quite a broad question. You can use GDI+ with F#, which will allow you to render graphics. Suggest you have a go and revise your question. Here is an example that uses GDI+ with F#: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/647/using-gdi-with-fsharp.aspx

Comment: You are right. I have now edited the question to not be as broad, and it now doesen't have anything to do with graphics since I already know how to draw shapes. Thanks for the link also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplistic idiomatic approach would be using standard data collection functions and combinators over the custom "dispatcher" function having signature `string*coord*coord -> (coord -> coord -> unit)`,  and set of processor functions, one for each shape. I.e. for a member of your list a simplistic dispatcher to a correspondent continuation processor may be:

```
let dispatcher = function
| (shape,startC,endC) when shape="rectangle" -> dorectangle startC endC
| (shape,startC,endC) when shape="ellipse" -> doellipse startC endC
| ...........
| _ -> failwith "Unknown shape"
```

where `doellipse` is a processor knowing how to draw ellipses , etc.

Then you use it as

```
[your list] |> List.iter dispatcher
```

Comment: `let drawList = list |> List.iter dispatcher` does not work. And istead of "dorectangle startC endC" I'm using `myGraphics.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, Point(x, y))`. The error is: `Type mismatch. Expecting a List<string*int*int> ref -> 'a   but given a 'b list -> unit   The type 'List<string*int*int> ref' does not match the type ''a list' `. And my list looks like following: `let list : (string * int * int) List ref = ref []`

Comment: If you find additional details really important, then why not providing them along with your original question? If you do
not mind putting all missing context into your original question I may accordingly adjust my otherwise quite generic answer. Besides,
your `let drawList...` doesn't make much sense within my assumptions as [`List.iter : ('T -> unit) -> 'T list -> unit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340469.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
[list] |> List.filter (fun e -> (fst e) = "rectangle") |> List.iter actionRectangle
[list] |> List.filter (fun e -> (fst e) = "ellipse") |> List.iter actionEllipse
```

Comment: some explanation would make wonders :)

Comment: I agree with david. I understand what filter and iter does for lists, but I'm not as experienced with the fun keyword and it's endless functionality. Im guessing (fst e) creates/gets the first value (assigned to fst) from item e in the list? If that would be true, why would it know it would assign the first value to fst?

Comment: fst gets first item of the tuple. Equals is not assignment, it is equality check. fun is simple lambda expression with one argument. Hope it helps.